# Clear input's value once it's a jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Need to clear the value of a jQuery object. Standard method isn't working for me, figure I'm missing something.

HTML

`<input class="file" type="file" />`

JavaScript

```
var file = $input.find('input.file');

    /*blahblahblah stuff*/

    file.value = '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you have a method to set the value `val(string)` you also use this to get the value of the input ie don't pass a string...

```
file.val('');
```

See api docs http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: i must admit it probably wouldn't have taken much to google this sort of thing - *jquery set input value*

Comment: Actually, I had, but I thought the doc said that it didn't accept any arguments.